# JQuery $.ajax not posting multiple vars

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi Guys I have the following function that is called on a link:onclick(), but for some reason the $.ajax does nothing at all - have even stripped my php code to only dump the $_POST var but I still get no feedback from the function - all i get is the alert msg - which is also just there for test purposes...

called there:

```
<a href="'.dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'&&act=Save " onclick="saveMyGame()">Save</a>

function saveMyGame(){

        var usern       = $('#usern').attr('value');
        var usrPoints   = $('#userPoints').attr('value');
        var usrLevel    = $('#userlevel').attr('value');

        var saveState   = this.imgPath;
        alert('Saving your game: '+usern+' Points: '+usrPoints+' Level: '+usrLevel+' state phase: '+saveState);
        e.preventDefault();
        var svGame = {act:'saveGame',user:usern, Points:usrPoints, Level:usrLevel, saveGState:saveState}    ;

            $.ajax({
                    url: "game/lib/updateGame.php",
                    type: "POST", 
                    cache: false, 
                    data: svGame, 
                    dataType: "html", 

                    success: function(svGame) {
                        $(".traget").html(svGame).fadeIn('slow');
                    }
                }); 

    }
```

the PHP code is suppose to check act, then verify that all required info is passed, than process the request or display an error msg...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['act']) && $_POST['act'] == 'saveGame') {
//Process save game request
/*if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['userPoints']) && isset($_POST['userLevel']) && isset($_POST['saveGState']) ) {
    $Game->saveGame();
    echo'<br>....'.$_POST['user'];
} else {
    echo 'Please provide correct information for saving...';
}
*/
echo var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Comment: do you get any Javascript errors?

Comment: Check your js console to see what has been sent to the server.

Comment: `the PHP code is suppose to check act` , where are you checking `act` in your code?

Comment: what is `this.imgPath` ?

Comment: Ensure that the `$.ajax` statement is reached, and that the JavaScript interpreter isn't aborting due to a previous error. Also, verify that the relative URL to your php page is correct.

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers this.imgPath is the filepath to the last dropped image.
I do not get any errors but for some unknown reason i get nothing...

Comment: `$(".traget")` or `$(".target")`

Comment: Also, never ever ever use `.attr('value')`. If it's a text box, in jQuery >= 1.6 this will only get you the initial value of the text box. Use the convenience function `.val()` instead, or access the value property through `.prop('value')`. Simplified explanation being that `.prop()` reflects the current value in memory as seen by JavaScript, as opposed to `.attr()` being the value in the markup!

Comment: try to add in php side `echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);` then alert response in ajax success , to see what you have missed

Comment: I'm not sure, but is `e.preventDefault` giving some error?
You didn't define "e" variable.

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers will do that no, theLibertine, i will update to event.
UweB that works just fine for me...
SajithNair, just a spelling error, div class is traget :)

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers i am confused.. what magic is that? :) it works just have to finish up the procesing now. AWESOME thanks all...

Answer (score -1):

**Url** in your ajax request has relative path `url: "game/lib/updateGame.php",` without slash in the beginning of the url like `url: "/game/lib/updateGame.php",`.
So maybe if your page adress differ from root (for example http://yourdomain.com/games/), full path will be http://yourdomain.com/games/game/lib/updateGame.php and therefore the server method is not performed.

Comment: `dataType` is the type that is returned by the server, it has no merit on `data`.